# Java compilation with external jars: cannot find symbol

Tags: java, war, jfreechart, javac

I'm trying to compile a war project like this

```
javac -classpath "/home/user/gwt-2.8.2/*:/home/user/externalJars/*:/home/user/myapp/src:/home/user/myapp/lib/*" -d build $(find * | grep "\.java")
```

but it throws an error

```
myapp/src/com/myorg/webservices/server/service/reports/jfreeCustomizers/barChart/BarChartHelper.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
import org.jfree.chart.StandardChartTheme;
                      ^
  symbol:   class StandardChartTheme
  location: package org.jfree.chart
myapp/src/com/myorg/webservices/server/service/reports/jfreeCustomizers/barChart/BarChartHelper.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.category.StandardBarPainter;
                                        ^
  symbol:   class StandardBarPainter
  location: package org.jfree.chart.renderer.category
myapp/src/com/myorg/webservices/server/service/reports/jfreeCustomizers/stackedAreaChart/TotalComparisonHelper.java:42: error: cannot find symbol
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.category.StandardBarPainter;
                                        ^
  symbol:   class StandardBarPainter
  location: package org.jfree.chart.renderer.category
myapp/src/com/myorg/webservices/server/service/reports/jfreeCustomizers/stackedAreaChart/NetSavingsHelper.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
import org.jfree.chart.StandardChartTheme;
                      ^
  symbol:   class StandardChartTheme
  location: package org.jfree.chart
myapp/src/com/myorg/webservices/server/service/reports/jfreeCustomizers/stackedAreaChart/TotalComparisonHelperV2.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.category.StandardBarPainter;
                                        ^
  symbol:   class StandardBarPainter
  location: package org.jfree.chart.renderer.category
5 errors
```

It's pretty strange because I have `jcommon-1.0.8.jar` and `jfreechart-1.0.7.jar` within `/home/user/externalJars/` directory. 
What is the possible reason of this unclean compilation?

```
javac -version
javac 11.0.2
java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_191"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-8u191-b12-2ubuntu0.18.04.1-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Please, do not suggest using ant/maven for a build. I want to understand better the process of compilation and how it works under the hood.

Comment: "I want to understand better the process of compilation and how it works under the hood." - Just out of curiosity: why? What do you hope to do with that knowledge?

Comment: Knowing everything doesn't always makes your life easier. Just go with the flow and do it like everyone else. IDE + Build Tool + Versioning Tool + Lots of coffee

Comment: Btw, why are those jars in "externalJars" and not in "myapp/lib"? They'd need to be present at runtime anyways so they should be direct dependencies of your application.

Comment: @Lino _especially_ lots of coffee ;)

Comment: Have you tried specifiying the jars explicitly in the command, rather than just the folder?  Also, you can "unzip" the jar files and check that the classes are in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the jfreechart Jar is of an old version. The class [StandardChartTheme](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/StandardChartTheme.html) is introduced in 1.0.11 (as per the linked Javadoc), and you're using 1.0.7.